# How to flag question related to the Arabic language?

Tags: discussion, bug, close-reasons

The question [Spelling of Thabbat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9213/3487) looks clearly [off-topic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because it is related to *The Arabic language itself* but in the flag dialog the off-topic reasons do not provide any such option to be be chosen from.

Why so? Am I missing anything?

Of course one could opt for the *"needs ♦ moderator attention"* but doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beta users with 500+ rep (the required rep to cast actual close votes on questions, rather than just flag them for review) can just close with a generic "off-topic."

Low-rep users are unable to do this because, according to a post on meta.SO, Stack Exchange is "[trying to restrict the use of flag-to-close to problems that are generally agreed-on by the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/132874)," which is to say only according to those close reasons so clearly established as to be on the custom list.  Right now, if a sub-500 user finds something that is clearly off-topic, flagging for diamond attention is the only real option available (short of flagging for the wrong reason entirely, which I don't recommend).

That said, I see no reason why a custom "Arabic language" off-topic reason shouldn't be added to the list, so I have written one.  It just needs approval from one of the other mods before it can go live.